# Best blog to upload mathematica .nb and CDF files

Tags: discussion, blog

What blog hosting websites are good and conducive to uploading mathematica notebook files? e.g. blogger, wordpress, google+ etc.

I will be applying to PhD programs in the near future, and I would like to have my collection of programs and projects uploaded somewhere where admissions offices can access them.

Note: I think this question belongs to meta, if not I'll move it.

Comment: Why do you want a blog and not just, say, a shared folder on DropBox or the like? Anyway, if you don't plan on modifying those files you could just make a publicly accessible git repository on GitHub or BitBucket. Beware that Mathematica notebooks [don't play along well](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26180/36089) with VCS, though.

Comment: @A.P. I'd like to have them somewhere where the reader can look at them while reading my comments on them. For example, Mathhen does it perfectly: http://blog.matthen.com/

Comment: I see what you mean, although personally I'd like some properly commented code (possibly in notebook form), instead. On that blog I found just brief descriptions of the animations shown, but the actual code for some of them was pretty hard to understand without proper comments -- although that may also be because I'm not very used to the Wolfram language, yet.

Comment: @A.P. Do you have any idea how he did it? Or what blog site he used? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean? I was just talking about the Matthen blog you linked to, which looks like a Tumblr microblog with a custom domain. The guy just uploaded the code to Pastebin and linked to it in his posts. Anyway, to get an idea of what I'm talking about in the previous post, have a look at the code from [this](http://blog.matthen.com/post/128409945246/in-mc-eschers-metamorphose-he-transforms-square): I find the code quite hard to read, and the description isn't really helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default you can only upload certain file types to a WordPress blog, and notebooks, .m files and CDFs are not among those that are allowed. However, by installing [Mathematica Toolbox](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mathematica-toolbox/) all of those types of files will be added to the whitelist.

Be aware that you can't install custom plugins to a WordPress blog hosted on wordpress.com.

A very simple solution is to put your files in a public DropBox folder and link to them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you mean that I need to download wordpress.org and and find someone to host it on my own? From what you're saying it sounds like if I have a regular wordpress.com blog I won't be able to use the toolbox. Is it possible to get wordpress.org and host it on wordpress.com?